# Highcharts line chart from a Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts, google-sheets, datetime-format

I have a Google spreadsheet with two columns:

- a Date/Time column with the format dd/mm/yyyy HH.MM.SS
- a Temperature column with numbers

The sample spreadsheet is public and everyone can modify it:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-W2c443tuaBTrE5aMOlBckAjHB-jIS2KLlB83EH8Zc0

I created a simple Highchart chart in this way:

```
$('#chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature Log'
    },
    xAxis: {
        text: 'Time',
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature'
        }
    },        
    data: {
         googleSpreadsheetKey: '1-W2c443tuaBTrE5aMOlBckAjHB-jIS2KLlB83EH8Zc0'
    }       
});
```

The chart works well and you can see here:

https://jsfiddle.net/itzuki87/f474dhuy/3/

The problem is that the x-axis doesn't render properly the datetime format, it start from 1 Jan 1970. Which is the correct format that I have to use? Do I have to change the spreadsheet or the script?

Thank you.

Comment: Please try to convert your dates into format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your dates into format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`